# Get the min and max from array of objects with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Let's say I have the following structure

```
var myArrofObjects =  [
    {prop1:"10", prop2:"20", prop3: "somevalue1"},
    {prop1:"11", prop2:"26", prop3: "somevalue2"},
    {prop1:"67", prop2:"78", prop3: "somevalue3"} ];
```

I need to find the min and max based on prop2, so here my numbers would be 20 and 78.

How can I write code in Underscore to do that?

Comment: [`_.min()`](http://underscorejs.org/#min), [`_.max()`](http://underscorejs.org/#max)

Comment: I'd probably just `each` and set min/max vals; there's no "min/max" just `min` and `max`. Sorting would take longer, but you could always sort and take first/last vals.

Comment: @Andreas. Yes, i know of these functions existence. However, I am asking something more specific, see question.

Comment: @Dave, I am not sure what min/max is. I need a min and a max. As in, 2 different values. I think the question is pretty clear.

Comment: @sarsnake: It's a hypothetical function that returns the min *and* max at the same time. But anyway, why isn't `_min` and `_max` good enough?

Comment: "something more specific" Have I missed something? You're looking for the min and max value of `prop2`... Just use the functions as shown in the example for `_.max()`

Comment: @sarsnake I agree, so was my comment: iterate over the list and keep min/max vals.

Answer (score 13):

You don't really need underscore for something like this.

```
Math.max(...arrayOfObjects.map(elt => elt.prop2));
```

If you're not an ES6 kind of guy, then

```
Math.max.apply(0, arrayOfObjects.map(function(elt) { return elt.prop2; }));
```

Use the same approach for minimum.

If you're intent on finding max and min at the same time, then

```
arrayOfObjects . 
  map(function(elt) { return elt.prop2; }) .
  reduce(function(result, elt) {
    if (elt > result.max) result.max = elt;
    if (elt < result.min) result.min = elt;
    return result;
  }, { max: -Infinity, min: +Infinity });
```

Comment: You do need Underscore if you want compatibility in older browsers.

Comment: Umm, which older browser?

Comment: As a note, max returns -Infinity for empty arrays.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the _.maxBy to find max value as follows.

```
var maxValObject = _.maxBy(myArrofObjects, function(o) { return o.prop2; });
```

or with the iteratee shorthand as follows

```
var maxValObject = _.maxBy(myArrofObjects, 'prop2');
```

similarly the _.minBy as well;

Ref: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#maxBy

Answer (score 2):

use _.max and _.property:

```
var max value = _.max(myArrofObjects, _.property('prop2'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use _.max as follows:

```
var max_object = _.max(myArrofObjects, function(object){return object.prop2})
```

Using a function as the second input will allow you to access nested values in the object as well.

Comment: Probably obvious, but note you need to do `max_object.prop2` to get the max value (since this returns the whole object).

Answer (score 0):

**Underscore**

use _.sortBy(..) to sort your object by a property

```
var sorted = _.sortBy(myArrofObjects, function(item){
    return item.prop2;
});
```

you will then get a sorted array by your prop1 property, `sorted[0]` is the min, and `sorted[n]` is the max

**Plain JS**

```
myArrofObjects.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.prop2 - b.prop2;
})
```

Comment: In the first example, I guess it should be `prop2`.

Comment: I can't really agree with this solution. You are doing a potentially expensive sort only to find the min and max.

Comment: yes, the idea is to have a sorted array for other future operations. I don't know OP's use case, but that's what I would have done