# New Method for Finding Min Value in Named Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I do not feel this is a duplicate. The only other answers are over five years old and am assuming methods have improved.**

What is the proper way to find the minimum value in a named array. For example, if my array looks like this:

```
let drink_prices = [
{brandy:25, name: "brandy drink"},
{whiskey:20, name: "whiskey drink"},
{vodka:46, name: "vodka drink"}
];
```

How would I find the lowest price? I thought a funky for loop would do it, but wondered if there was a way to use Math.min() but didn't see a way for what I'm doing.

Advice?

Comment: Are you asking for the corresponding key for that value, the value itself, or both? Also, this is an object, not a "named array". JavaScript has no associative arrays.

Comment: `Math.min(...Object.values(drink_prices))`  But do you want the fact is `whiskey`?

Comment: @meagar - I used the name "Named Array" as a visual reference as it wasn't the standard single value array. 

I am wanting the min value for all the "drinks", so in my example, "20"

Comment: @Keith - all I need is min value, so the "20" in the example I gave. Don't need any of the "drink" names

Comment: You've edited the question and now the object format is really inconvenient. If you have any control over it, the price should be a property of the object: `{price: 25, name: 'brandy'}`. It's a poor design choice to have different property names all pointing to the same sort of thing.

Comment: Your modified question would still be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351934/get-the-min-and-max-from-array-of-objects-with-underscore-js, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985132/how-do-you-find-min-max-of-a-property-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects etc.

Comment: @Mark_M - yes, edited as it got marked as duplicate and I was forced to make it unique. I was trying to avoid a For Each loop but I do have control over the array so can simplify it to make things easier.

Comment: You have now modified to use an array,  but in a way that doesn't now make any sense, your key names keep changing..  You could do -> `Math.min(...drink_prices.map(v=>Object.values(v)[0]))`, but this is assuming the first  key is the one your interested in.